# Drupal CSS Aggregation breaks theme on Production

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-7

I am working on Bootstrap theme on Drupal 7. The site works fine, but when I activate CSS aggregation all theming breaks down on Production, In local environment css aggregation works fine. On local environment aggregated files are getting creating in /sites/default/files/css. On server I have given 777 permission to css folder.

Does anyone have any idea where to look?

Thanks

Comment: What does break down means? What is the exact problem, could you please give an example.

Comment: I resolved the issue as as in Drupal css aggregation css folder get created in sites/default/files/css. css folder was not writable on server, thats why aggregated css files were not getting created in css folder. After giving root user permissions ex) www-data:www-data on ubuntu server, css files got created and issue resolved as styling was available.

Comment: great to hear that!!!